# PowerApps submit checkbox and username to a list

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, sharepoint-list, powerapps-formula

I have a PowerApp I have been working on that presents some data from an excel table in a Gallery,

I have added to this gallery a tickbox as shown below.

[AppExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4uVu.png)

The purpose of the app is that multiple users can access the app, tick multiple boxes, and then click save.

Obviously with multiple people picking multiple options there will be overlaps between them, these need to be recorded.

I have created a list in sharepoint "AcademicChoices" and given it the extra column of "Volunteer"

[ListExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klo4e.png)

How I imagine this will work is that when the user has ticked some boxes and click "Save" it will send the "Project Title" to the "Title" column, and the username of the person logged into the app to the "Volunteer" column for each of their ticked items.

Here is a crude example of how it would work assuming that the user of the powerapps username was "stan"

[ChoicesMockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idjPb.png) [ListMockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/144u4.png)

From my research so far I can see that it can be achieved with Patch or SubmitForm but I have not had any luck with either of these.

Thanks.

Editing this to add the code I have

So I have the following

```
If(
    Checkbox1.Value=true,
    Patch(
          'AcademicChoices', 
           Defaults('AcademicChoices'), 
           {
              Title: ThisItem.student, 
              Volunteer: User().FullName
           }
     )
 )
```

This works, however it does not record the value of the field project, "Title: ThisItem.student, " I tried changing the string to

```
        If(
        Checkbox1.Value=true,
        Patch(
              'AcademicChoices', 
               Defaults('AcademicChoices'), 
               {
                  Student: ThisItem.student, 
                  Title: ThisItem.project, 
                  Volunteer: User().FullName
               }
         ),
Checkbox1.Value=false,
        Remove(
              'AcademicChoices', 
               Defaults('AcademicChoices'), 
               {
                  Student: ThisItem.student, 
                  Title: ThisItem.project, 
                  Volunteer: User().FullName
               }
         )
     )
```

This works to a degree, but as soon as I add the Checkbox1.Value=false, section and untick the boxes it will not actually remove the data from the list

Comment: Do you mind posting what your Patch or SubmitForm formulas are? Perhaps that will help in understanding what's going wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try and add your values to a collection first then probably have a button to then patch it to the data source when you are done, rather than communicating with the data source directly which is why the data is been removed from the list when you uncheck it